# Simplest way to send two ints over a TCP connection

Tags: java, android, c, tcp, struct

I want to be able to send two ints over a tcp connection. the client is an android application which gets the coordinates of the user input and then sends them to a c server program. I've managed to achieve the desired result but it is not very efficient. What i've done is turn the two ints into a single string separated by a comma and then send the single string over tcp. e.g `int x = 12;` and `int y = 34;` turns into `String to_send = "12,34";`. The server receives this string and then separates out the coordinates using strtok() and converts them back to ints using atoi().

This gives me what i want but i'm aware that it uses alot more memory then needed as each string character represents one byte. Could i send a struct over tcp which contained two shorts x and y? If so could you give me a little bit of sample code and some explanation that would be fantastic.

Tom

Comment: If you use an output stream to send data you could use `stream.writeInt(myint);'. Not all stream types have a writeInt(). So you have to search for the right one. Sorry don't know which one from memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use DataOutputStream.writeInt() or .writeShort().

Comment: Yes in Java one can use structs. I always declare them as class then. Works ok. ;-).

Comment: @greenapps That would be a class then, not a struct.

Comment: A class'ical implementation of a struct'ure ?